# Retrieving the primary key from a database

Tags: c#, sql, database

Is it possible to return the last primary key given in a database?

This is partly how I'm connecting to and adding stuff to my database, but if you need more infor please ask.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da;

DataSet sessions;
```

Main

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

    sessions = new DataSet();

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\md\\PokerDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

    con.Open();

    string sql = "SELECT * From Sessions";
    da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
    da.Fill(sessions, "Sessions");

    con.Close();

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb;
    cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da);

    DataTable dt = sessions.Tables["Sessions"];


    DataRow table = sessions.Tables["Sessions"].Rows[position];
    table[0] = "Some Data";
    table[1] = "Some Data";
    table[2] = "Some Data";
    table[3] = 2;
    table[4] = 3;
    sessions.Tables["Sessions"].Rows[2].Delete();
    sessions.Tables["Sessions"].Rows.InsertAt(table, 2);

    da.Update(sessions, "Sessions");
}
}
```

Thanks for having a look!

Comment: What do you mean by "last primary key?" Do you mean the last *inserted* primary key?

Comment: I marked this back up. I think it's highly unfair to mark someone down for asking a question!

Comment: Hi, and thanks for answering! Yes, I meant the last primary key. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are asking for the last inserted primary key value? Then `SCOPE_IDENTY` is your friend. Take a [look here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190315.aspx) for detailed information

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Yaroslav. I'm still having some trouble understanding. What would I do with SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() in my code?

Comment: From your code, inmediately after the insert, you should call this statement, the value it returns is your last primary key inserted. I do not know what are you trying to achieve but maybe you will want to wrap your insert (and something else if needed) on a stored procedure and include at the end a call to the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. In that way with one call you will have it all done.

Comment: I'm still not really understanding how to use SCOPE_IDENTITY(). After the line da.Update(sessions, "Sessions"), can I just make an integer variable, say int prmKey; and then prmKey = SCOPE_IDENTITY("sessions"); Thanks again

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675364/scope-identity-in-batched-sqlclient-commands and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633821/scope-identity-always-returning-0  Those answers I think will be of great help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the last primary key from a table and you have it increments automatically on every insert, then you can just ask for its maximal value. If you want from the database, then you can use scope identity.